# {node / discord js} Restarting bot's entire script on error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I'm trying to have my bot restart ENTIRELY on encountering an error. The reason why I don't just let it sift through connection errors is because, whenever I encounter an internet issue, code starts repeating multiple times since the original node process hasn't been terminated, which technically I could fix but other connections to external apis stop working too. So ignoring fixing singular issues, I just want to restart entirely.

What I'm doing currently is using node child_process, with this function:

```
spawn(process.argv.shift(), process.argv, {
    cwd: process.cwd(),
    detached : true,
    stdio: "inherit"
});
process.exit();
```

I do know stdio inherit does nothing, since its exiting the parent process, but it doesn't really change anything to put it to ignore so i've just left it. Basically this works in theory, if I use a command to execute this, i can do it over and over and over and it will work fine, singular discord client, no repeats, it's up, i just can't monitor it since my original terminal is disconnected, and I can use a command to exit the current process so it's not stuck since I don't have a terminal to ctrl-c. But once put in practice, executing the function in bot.on("error") by disconnecting my internet seems to work, it ends the first process, but upon regaining internet there is no client connected.

My guess here: bot.on("error") will not be re-executed in the next process due to no discord client being made.

So I don't know if I'm making this too complicated or if I need to add a lot more. If this is the best way to do it then all I would need to solve is to wait until I have internet back and then make a new process or something like that. I'm not educated in fiddling with node so if any answers could be beginner friendly (mainly for node) i'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.on("error", (err) => {
process.exit(0)
});
```

Should work, it'll restart the bot when there's an error.

Unsure what you mean by

> My guess here: bot.on("error") will not be re-executed in the next process due to no discord client being made.

As long as you bot it in the same code as your startup, it'll restart the bot.

Comment: process.exit will exit the entire process, not restart it

Comment: Only if it's a one time instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a batch-file to run your bot simply add `:a` before the `node .` and `goto a` at the end.

Comment: I use a .js file, not batch. That could work though if I could communicate between the batch file and the js file but i doubt it

Comment: No, i meant you could put the `node index.js` in a batch file with that extra code I told you.